# How to handle errors using match within a closure in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a key bind closure with error handling that can execute a couple of instructions if `S` is pressed on the keyboard, but it seems like it's expecting a `()` and found enum Result.

```
use thirtyfour_sync::{error::WebDriverError, Keys::Enter, prelude::*};
use inputbot::KeybdKey::*;

pub fn bing() -> WebDriverResult<()>{

    let browser = DesiredCapabilities::edge();
    let driver = WebDriver::new("http://localhost:4444", &browser)?;
    driver.get("https://www.bing.com")?;

    SKey.bind(|| -> Result<(), WebDriverError>{
        match driver{             
            _ => {
                let main_element = driver.find_element(By::Id("sb_form_c"))?;
                let sec_element = main_element.find_element(By::Id("sb_form_q"))?;
                sec_element.send_keys("ksiOlajidebt")?;
                sec_element.send_keys(Enter)?;
                Ok(())
            },

            NoSuchElement => {
                let top_bar = driver.find_element(By::Id("sb_form_q"))?;
                top_bar.send_keys("ksimon")?;
                top_bar.send_keys(Enter)?;
                Ok(())
            }
        }
    });

    inputbot::handle_input_events();
    Ok(())
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<[closure@

src/edge.rs:10:19: 31:10] as FnOnce<()>>::Output == ()`
   --> src/edge.rs:10:14
    |
10  |         SKey.bind(|| -> Result<(), WebDriverError>{
    |              ^^^^ expected `()`, found enum `Result`
    |
    = note: expected unit type `()`
                    found enum `Result<(), WebDriverError>`
note: required by a bound in `KeybdKey::bind`
   --> /root/.cargo/git/checkouts/inputbot-ca044018c1f51f7c/b91aec3/src/public.rs:136:20
    |
136 |     pub fn bind<F: Fn() + Send + Sync + 'static>(self, callback: F) {
    |                    ^^^^ required by this bound in `KeybdKey::bind`
```

I  don't know if this is something to do with the crate itself, because it will only expect `()`. Any work around for this?

Comment: The `match` has nothing to do with it. `?` returns from the closure, not just from the `match`.

Answer (score 0):

[`KeybdKey::bind()`](https://docs.rs/inputbot/latest/inputbot/enum.KeybdKey.html#method.bind) has this signature:

```
pub fn bind<F: Fn() + Send + Sync + 'static>(self, callback: F)
```

So indeed you can't return a `Result` from the given `callback`. You will somehow need to handle the error yourself within the handler.

You can start by extracting the handler into a function `handle_s_key` that *does* return a `Result`. That lets you use the `?` syntactic sugar inside that function.

That leaves the question how to handle errors returned by that function; the options are the usual, e.g. panic, log or silently ignore the error.